# Cannot delete / move Mails on Office365

Tags: mail.app, office-365

MacOX 13.1 (22C65)

My Mac Mail App is connected to an office 365 account via exchange. I have the following weird situation:

Using Outlook/Web: When I delete a message from the Inbox in Outlook/Web, it disappears on from Mac Mail within a few seconds. So everything seems to be synchronized.

Using Mac Mail: When I delete a message from the Inbox, it disappears from the local inbox but it stays in the inbox of Outlook/Web, so things get out of sync.

When I delete a message on Outlook/Android, it disappears from Outlook/Web.

What can I do to keep Mac Mail and Outlook/Web synchronized.

**Side Note**

I have another separate Office 365 Account that is also connected. When I delete a message from this account from Mac Mail, it disappears from Outlook/Web.

Mac Mail:

When I move a message with attachments from the Office 365 inbox to a local inbox, the attachments are lost.

When I move a message with attachments from the Office 365 inbox to another Office 365 folder, the attachments are kept.

Any ideas would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I used to work for a company that had iPhones and MS Exchange and about a third of the people had all sorts of issues between mail.app & calendar.app and the exchange server. In all cases when I could talk them into it switching to the (free) MS Outlook app solved all of those problems. Apple's mail and calendar app are good apps but don't always work and play well with MS Exchange (local and cloud versions).

Comment: While searching the internet for solutions I found that a lot of people have similar problems with outlook for mac, so for now I might switch to outlook / web, which is probably what Microsoft is expecting from us anyways.

Comment: The Outlook webmail client is actually pretty good, looks and acts like a native app...